# How can I get the reason for WiFi disconnect broadcast

Tags: java, android

I have a manifest registered BroadcastReceiver that I am using to monitor WiFi disconnects. I receive a disconnect broadcast every time the device scans for WiFi. I need some way to determine if the broadcast was a result of scanning for WiFi or the device actually disconnected from a network.

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(!intent.getAction().equals("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"))
            return;
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                if(networkInfo.getDetailedState() == CONNECTED || networkInfo.getDetailedState() == DISCONNECTED)
                    PresenceData.loadData(context);
                if(networkInfo.getDetailedState() == CONNECTED) {
                    System.out.println("Wifi connected");
                    PresenceData.sendNotification("Wifi Connected", "You are now connected to " + PresenceData.getCurrentWifiSSID(context), context);
                    PresenceData.submitChanges(context);
                } else if(networkInfo.getDetailedState() == DISCONNECTED) {
                    System.out.println("Wifi Disconnected");
                    PresenceData.sendNotification("Wifi Disconnected", "Your wifi has disconnected", context);
                    UpdaterService.scheduleUpdate(context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what code you have

Comment: Ok, Just added it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [NetworkInfo.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html) to get the current state of the network. There are enumerations for all kinds of possible states, such as failures, successes, scanning, etc. Below is a sample on how to retrieve the info:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
    this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    System.out.println("Network Status " + info.getDetailedState().name());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already using that but my problem is that after it scans it will say disconnected. I'm trying to determine if the WiFi recently disconnected or if it just scanned.